# Spring Boot common library how to provide common profile-specific properties

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Our team needs to create a shared library that calls collaborator services and processes them with a common logic. The library will require a list of properties, such as URLs and databases, which should be chosen based on the application profile being used. Since we want to avoid code duplication, we would prefer not to repeat the configuration in all client projects.

there could be cases where multiple profiles are active, causing the configuration to fail. We could use more-specific configurations or a custom property provider, but what would be the best approach?

The following code is an example of shared functionality and configuration:

```
@PropertySources({
        @PropertySource("classpath:/library.default.properties"),
        @PropertySource(value = "classpath:/library.config-${spring.profiles.active}.properties", ignoreResourceNotFound = true)
})
public class MyConfigurationFile {
```

We can use more-specific configurations or even some custom property provider but what would be the best or recommended approach. Our main goal is to avoid repeating the same configuration in all client projects and be able to share it within the library.

How can we do it following the best practices?

p.s
just an example of the shared functionality and configuration (a bit artificial)

*AccountMangeService* needs to call a couple rest endopints and do some DB lookup +validation

```
class AccountMangeService{
   @Value("${account.url})
   String accountUrl;
   @Value("${our.dbaccount.jdbc})
   String dbJdbc;

  isPrincipalAuthoreisedForAccoutn(Principal user, String account){
     Data data=getAccountInfo(accountUrl,account);
     return jdbcTempalae.select(somequrty,user.getName,account) 
  } 
}
```

properties

```
#--local
account.url=localhost:9999/wiremock/accounts
our.dbaccount.jdbc=H2Db

#--dev
account.url=https:/dev.accounts.mycompany.com/
our.dbaccount.jdbc=jdbc:postgresql://db456.nonprod.db.mycompany.com/db15
#--qa
account.url=https:/qa.accounts.mycompany.com/
our.dbaccount.jdbc=jdbc:postgresql://db123.nonprod.db.mycompany.com/db16
```

Comment: I would do it with a class annotated with ConfigurationProperties annotation and a meaningful prefix. Similar to that used by Hibernate or Kafka. Your library should not care about profiles. Just document the properties needed and clients should set them accordingly.

Comment: The problem is that we have quite a few properties for ENV. and they are repeated for every client. I would like to avoid this duplication.

Comment: No duplication at all with the solution proposed above. Let me put an example together.

Answer (score 0):

I would implement it with a single class annotated with `@ConfigurationProperties` and a meaningful prefix. Similar to that used by Hibernate or Kafka. Your library should not care about profiles. Just document the properties needed and clients should set them accordingly.

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "drphil.library") 
@ConfigurationPropertiesScan 
public class DrPhilLibraryProperties { 

    private String accountUrl; 
    private String ourDbacountJdbc; 

    // standard getters and setters 
}
```

And client will set:

```
# in application-local.properties
drphil.library.account.url=localhost:9999/wiremock/accounts
drphil.library.our.dbaccount.jdbc=H2Db

# in application-dev.properties
drphil.library.account.url=https:/dev.accounts.mycompany.com/
drphil.library.our.dbaccount.jdbc=jdbc:postgresql://db456.nonprod.db.mycompany.com/db15

# ...
```

Comment: it is nice to have a common prefix (in fact the properties already do have it ) but this approach doesn't solve the problem that every client has provide those properties for every profile. So if i have 5 properties and 10 clients i have a duplication of 4x5 = property values duplicated 10 times